# OpenCV Videocapture vs FFMPEG irregularities in PTS / PTS_TIME calculation

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG scene detection to split videos on edits. The scene detection isn't perfect, but good enough for the purpose. The trouble starts when I try to extract frames using OpenCV.

With scene detection, the frames are filtered, so the frame numbers are just the ones selected. What I still get is the PTS though, and the PTS_TIME. I checked some of those calculations from FFMPEG, and they all appear correct. To see pairs of frame number to PTS, I use this:

```
ffmpeg -i $CLIP -filter:v "showinfo" -f null -
```

If now use

```
  vc.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, int(pts_time*1000.0))
```

I then test the frame number with:

```
  vc.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
```

i get the same frame number that ffmpeg would show at this point. However - for some clips, this is slightly off - usually 1 or sometimes 2 frames.

So where FFMPEG sees this (without any filtering):

```
  Stream #0:0(und)
  24 fps, 24 tbr, 24k tbn, 48 tbc (default)
  [...]
  n:1175 pts:1177000 pts_time:49.0417
```

OpenCV sees this:

```
  pts_time: 49.04178 / frame: 1177
```

as you can see, this is 2 frames off. For a "good" clip, I get from FFMPEG:

```
  Stream #0:0(eng): 
  23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default) (original)
  [...]
  n:3122 pts: 130213 pts_time:130.213
```

and OpenCV sees the same:

```
  pts_time: 130.2130 / frame: 3122
```

The offset in the "bad" clip is constant (2 frames) throughout the entire clip, so I think this is not a rounding error of some sort. Is this OpenCV making a BooBoo?

I could use the Information from FFMPEG to pick a frame number in OpenCV and set CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES instead of CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC ... but it would be a bit troublesome, since i would need to parse out the TBN, and since "-print_format json" still is a cruel joke rather than anything useful, I am trying to avoid that ...

How can I make this frame accurate?

.rm

Comment: I don't think you can set the timestamps using  `vc.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC`. I suppose `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` is meant to be used for only reading and not for setting. I don't know if OpenCV making a BooBoo, but if it does, consider using PyAV for reading the frames and the timestamps instead of using OpenCV.

Comment: @Rotem thank you for your comment. i'll check out pyav. however, setting POS_MSEC works perfectly in 9 our of 10 cases - and the remainder isn't far off either (max 2 frames).

Comment: I don't understand what you are actually asking. Are you asking how to get the accurate PTS timestamp of a captured video frame? When capturing the frames, are you reading the frames sequentially, or is there video seeking in the process? Why do your need the timestamp and can't be satisfied with the frame number?

Comment: opencv is not for video decoding, nor for accurate seeking or accurate time stamps, but for computer vision. use ffmpeg directly, via PyAV.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz but what good is it to look at frames if i dont get the one i am asking for?

Comment: @Rotemi would like to extract specific frames from a video for analysis, and i would like that to be precise. so, given what information i have, i am interested in how to get to that point.

Comment: @rmalchow you can expect OpenCV to decode a video file *sequentially*, and give you the frames. any metadata _might_ be untrustworthy. seeking is a complex task. if you need this fixed, check for existing bugs or else file one (with a [mre]!) or work on OpenCV's source yourself to fix the issue... or use PyAV/ffmpeg instead.

Comment: I would **not** recommend anything based on ffmpeg *subprocesses*. it's a library. it should be used as a library.

Answer (score 1):

For getting accurate timestamps, we may use FFmpeg subprocess with [NUT muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/nut.html), and reading the raw video frames from stdout pipe.

The NUT Container format is described [here](https://ffmpeg.org/%7Emichael/nut.txt).
Parsing the NUT container with Python is not an easy job (and also very efficient it terms of execution time).
The following solution may be a good for testing purposes.

---

Start by creating a synthetic MP4 video file using FFmpeg CLI (to be used as input):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=100 -vf "setpts='(N+100)/1/TB'" -vcodec libx264 in.mp4`

`setpts` filter is used for setting the PTS start counting from 100:
PTS are going to be `100.0`, `101.0`, `102.0`, `103.0`...

---

The following code extracts the timestamps from the NUT container, read the raw video frame, and write the timestamps as text on the video:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np
import subprocess as sp
import shlex
import struct

# Preparing 1Hz MP4 video file for testing:
# Use setpts filter for setting the PTS start counting from 100: PTS are going to be 100, 101, 102, 103...
# ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=100 -vf "setpts='(N+100)/1/TB'" -vcodec libx264 in.mp4

input_file_name = 'in.mp4'


def read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe):
    """ Read "variable length" unsigned value according to https://ffmpeg.org/~michael/nut.txt. """
    value = 0
    more_data = 1
    n_bytes_read = 0
    while more_data:
        data_byte = ord(stdout_pipe.read(1))
        n_bytes_read += 1
        more_data = data_byte >> 7  # Upper bit
        data = data_byte & 0x7F  # Lower 7 bits
        value = 128*value + data
        
    return (value, n_bytes_read)


def read_variable_length_value_signed(stdout_pipe):
    """ Read "variable length" signed value according to https://ffmpeg.org/~michael/nut.txt. """
    temp, n_bytes_read = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    temp += 1
    if temp & 1:
        value = -(temp >> 1)
    else:
        value = (temp >> 1)
    return (value, n_bytes_read)



def read_nut_packet_header(first_byte, stdout_pipe):
    """ 
    Read NUT packet header according to https://ffmpeg.org/~michael/nut.txt.
    Return startcode and forward_ptr (number of bytes to read to the end of the packet).
    """
    startcode_bytes = first_byte + stdout_pipe.read(7) # Read 7 bytes startcode (excluding first_byte = 'N's)
    startcode = struct.unpack('>Q', startcode_bytes)[0]
    forward_ptr = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)[0]

    if forward_ptr > 4096:
        header_checksum = stdout_pipe.read(4)

    return (startcode, forward_ptr)


def read_nut_packet_footer(stdout_pipe):
    checksum = stdout_pipe.read(4)


def read_nut_main_header(stdout_pipe, forward_ptr):
    """ 
    Read NUT main header according to https://ffmpeg.org/~michael/nut.txt.
    Return the timebase.
    """
    version, n_bytes0 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    if (version > 3):
        minor_version, n_bytes1 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    else:
        n_bytes1 = 0
    stream_count, n_bytes2 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    max_distance, n_bytes3 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    time_base_count, n_bytes4 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)  # time_base_count must be 1, because we assume there is only video stream.
    assert time_base_count == 1, 'time_base_count != 1, but we assume there is only one stream'
    time_base_num, n_bytes5 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)  # We suppuse to loop over time_base_count, but we assume time_base_count=1.
    time_base_denom, n_bytes6 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    time_base = time_base_num/time_base_denom
    n_bytes_read = n_bytes0 + n_bytes1 + n_bytes2 + n_bytes3 + n_bytes4 + n_bytes5 + n_bytes6
    nut_main_header_remainder = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(forward_ptr - n_bytes_read)  # Read remaining bytes
    return time_base
            



def read_nut_stream_header(stdout_pipe, forward_ptr):
    """ 
    Rad NUT stream header with partial decoding for getting frame resolution 
    Return (width, height) for video stream and (-1, -1) for other type of streams
    """
    width, height = -1, -1
    stream_id, n_bytes0 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    stream_class, n_bytes1 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    fourcc_len, n_bytes2 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    fourcc = stdout_pipe.read(fourcc_len)  # b'BGR\x18'
    time_base_id, n_bytes3 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    msb_pts_shift, n_bytes4 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    max_pts_distance, n_bytes5 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    decode_delay, n_bytes6 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    stream_flags, n_bytes7 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    codec_specific_data_len, n_bytes8 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)
    codec_specific_data = stdout_pipe.read(codec_specific_data_len)
    n_bytes_read = n_bytes0 + n_bytes1 + n_bytes2 + n_bytes3 + n_bytes4 + n_bytes5 + n_bytes6 + n_bytes7 + n_bytes8 + fourcc_len + codec_specific_data_len
    if (stream_class == 0):  # stream_class 0 applies video (it must be a video stream)
        width, n_bytes9 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)  # 192
        height, n_bytes10 = read_variable_length_value(stdout_pipe)  # 108S
        n_bytes_read += (n_bytes9 + n_bytes10)
            
    nut_stream_header_remainder = stdout_pipe.read(forward_ptr - n_bytes_read)  # Read remaining bytes

    return (width, height)


# Execute FFmpeg as sub-process (stdout pipe is configured as output).
# Select RAW video codec and NUT container (https://ffmpeg.org/nut.html)
# Use -copyts flag for keeping the original timestamps
# Use -an -sn -dn for ignoring audio, subtitels and data streams (keeping only the video stream).
ffmpeg_cmd = shlex.split(f'ffmpeg -vsync 0 -copyts -an -sn -dn -i {input_file_name} -pix_fmt bgr24 -vcodec rawvideo -f nut -write_index 0 pipe:')

# Open sub-process that gets in_stream as input and uses stdout as an output PIPE.
ffmpeg_process = sp.Popen(ffmpeg_cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE)


# https://www.ffmpeg.org/~michael/nut.txt
nut_file_id_string = b"nut/multimedia container\0"
main_startcode = 0x7A561F5F04AD + (((ord('N')<<8) + (ord('M')))<<48)
stream_startcode = 0x11405BF2F9DB + (((ord('N')<<8) + (ord('S')))<<48)
syncpoint_startcode = 0xE4ADEECA4569 + (((ord('N')<<8) + (ord('K')))<<48)
index_startcode = 0xDD672F23E64E + (((ord('N')<<8) + (ord('X')))<<48)
info_startcode = 0xAB68B596BA78 + (((ord('N')<<8) + (ord('I')))<<48)

# Read file ID string (25 bytes)
nbytes = len(nut_file_id_string)
file_id_string = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(nbytes)  # Read file_id_string
if file_id_string != nut_file_id_string:
    raise Exception('file_id_string != nut_file_id_string')


while True:
    # https://www.ffmpeg.org/~michael/nut.txt
    # packet_header
    next_byte = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(1)

    if len(next_byte) != 1:
        print('Error reading next byte - end of file!')  # Break the loop - end of file.
        break

    if next_byte == b'N':
        startcode, forward_ptr = read_nut_packet_header(next_byte, ffmpeg_process.stdout)
        
        if startcode == main_startcode:
            video_time_base = read_nut_main_header(ffmpeg_process.stdout, forward_ptr)
        elif startcode == stream_startcode:
            (width, height) = read_nut_stream_header(ffmpeg_process.stdout, forward_ptr)
        elif startcode == info_startcode:
            nut_info_packet = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(forward_ptr)
        elif startcode == index_startcode:
            nut_index = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(forward_ptr)
        elif startcode == syncpoint_startcode:
            global_key_pts, n_bytes_read = read_variable_length_value(ffmpeg_process.stdout)
            #id = global_key_pts % time_base_count  # Skip this conversion, because we assume time_base_count=1 
            #value= (global_key_pts // time_base_count) * time_base[id]
            syncpoint = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(forward_ptr - n_bytes_read)
            checksum = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(4)  # Assume only checksum after syncpoint

            raw_frame = ffmpeg_process.stdout.read(width*height*3)  # Read raw video frame as bytes array

            if len(raw_frame) != (width*height*3):
                print('Error reading frame!!!')  # Break the loop in case of an error (too few bytes were read).
                break

            pts = global_key_pts*video_time_base  # Scale global_key_pts by video stream time-base - convert timestamp to seconds

            # Transform the bytes read into a NumPy array, and reshape it to video frame dimensions
            frame = np.frombuffer(raw_frame, np.uint8).reshape((height, width, 3))

            # Draw the timestamp over the frame
            cv2.putText(frame, str(pts), (20, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 0), 2)

            # Show frame for testing
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(100)

            if key == 27:
                break
        else:
             print('Error: unknown startcode!!!')
      
ffmpeg_process.stdout.close()
ffmpeg_process.wait()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

The above code is too long to be explained in details...
The parsing procedure follows the [NUT Container Format documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/%7Emichael/nut.txt), with few assumptions (assuming there is only video stream for example).

---

Sample output frame:
[image]